# How to use self.method() in class creation time?

Tags: python

In some cases, I want to use instance method in class creation time.

**I just want to use self in permissions list..This is my question**

But it does not work. Is it some ways to solve the problem?

```
class PermissionChecker(object):
    # how to use self in class create time.
    permissions = [self.is_superuser(), self.is_god()]

    def is_superuser(self):
        # use self.property just like self.name...
        return True

    def is_god(self):
        return True

class Child(PermissionChecker):
    permissions = PermissionChecker.permissions + [self.is_coder(),]

    def is_coder(self):
        return True
```

Comment: I don't see any properties in your example code. What do you mean, exactly? Note that by property I mean using the `property` descriptor.

Comment: And you cannot use `self` in the `permissions` list; it is being executed at class creation time, not when accessing `permissions`.

Comment: I think your question would be much clearer if you explained what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to call self.permissions in my case in English. So i called it class property..

Comment: I just want to use self in permissions list..This is my question.

Comment: `self` doesn't exist unless you have an instance @chenchiyuan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing the term `attribute` with `property`; you cannot use `self` in the class definition itself, it is only available to a method.

I think you are looking for the [`property` descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class PermissionChecker(object):
    @property
    def permissions(self):
        return [self.is_superuser(), self.is_god()]

    def is_superuser(self):
        # use self.property just like self.name...
        return True

    def is_god(self):
        return True
```

By using `property` (above used as a `@` decorator) you turn a method into an attribute:

```
>>> pcheck = PermissionChecker()
>>> pcheck.permissions
[True, True]
```

The `permissions` method is called every time the `.permissions` attribute is accessed on an instance.

Alternatively, set the list in the `__init__` initializer:

```
class PermissionChecker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.permissions = [self.is_superuser(), self.is_god()]

    def is_superuser(self):
        # use self.property just like self.name...
        return True

    def is_god(self):
        return True
```

Comment: I update my question. My problem is how to use self in permissions list.

Comment: @chenchiyuan: Which you cannot do without a property.

Comment: If i don't want to define it in __init__ method, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @chenchiyuan: I gave you the two ways to solve it. You cannot use `self` in a class definition; you *need* a method for that to be bound.

Comment: I want to define it in class. When i see the class, i know what permissions it has, and it's easy to add or delete other permissions.

Comment: @chenchiyuan: Then define it in `__init__` or use a property.

Comment: When define using self.method is what i wanted. I know how to solve this problem using init method or property. But my problem is just using self.method in class create time.

Comment: @chenchiyuan: Last time: `self` is *never* defined when creating a class. You need an instance for `self` to be bound *to*. You cannot solve that problem, I'm afraid. Redefine your problem in terms *not* using an instance and you can solve it at class creation time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to provide a property.  This can be done like so:

```
class PermissionChecker(object):
    def _get_permissions(self):
        return [self.is_superuser(), self.is_god()]

    permissions = property(_get_permissions)

    def is_superuser(self):
        # use self.property just like self.name...
        return True

    def is_god(self):
        return True
```

Comment: You got your syntax all mixed up there; you cannot call `self._get_permissions()` to make it a property.

Comment: Sorry, I don't explain clearly of my question.I update it now.